# Supplying curl with multiple options that require <file or input>

Tags: bash, command-line, curl, http

I'm trying to execute a curl command from the terminal.

- I need to provide HTTP authentication
- I need to POST a .jar file

This works when HTTP authentication is disabled:

```
curl --data-binary @~/file.jar localhost:8090/jars/test100
```

And this works when HTTP authention is enabled:

```
curl --netrc-file ~/.curl_password_file localhost:8090
```

However, combining both options does **not** work when HTTP authentication is enabled. The error returned is:

```
curl: (3) <url> malformed
The resource requires authentication, which was not supplied with the request%
```

I've tried combining both the `--data-binary` and `--netrc-file` options in all sorts of different ways. Nothing :(

Any ideas?